# MySql To Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I Have been using Eclipse to connect my project using mysql ..

To connect with my sql i'am using mysql connector in my context.xml file

this is my context.xml file

```
<Context reloadable="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    maxActive="300" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/tds" password="xxx"
    autoReconnect="true" removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.101:3306/tds?autoConnect=true"
    username="xxx" />
```

I want to store milliseconds also in my project ,so i migrated from mysql to mariadb..

So,I downloaded mariadb connector and added as a external jar file in my project..

and changed the context file to

```
<Context reloadable="true" antiResourceLocking="true">
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    maxActive="300" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/tds" password="xxx"
    autoReconnect="true" removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mariadb://192.168.1.101:3306/tds?autoConnect=true"
    username="xxx" />
```

but it gives me error in my java files,i.e in lines like this

```
import java.sql.Connection;
```

`import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;`

Like in these lines it showing error,also same in some other java files also..

I don't know what is the problem is..

Comment: Can you include the error stack trace output?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `com.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` for `org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver` in `driverClassName`